# I would like to add a post commit hook so that if a user deletes a file, I will be notified by email

Tags: svn, post-commit, svn-hooks

I would like to add a post commit hook so that if a user deletes particular file, I will be notified by email..

Help !!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing! (Your question would get more attention if you actually asked a question, instead of just presenting your case)

Comment: This looks rather similar to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473842/svn-post-commit-hook-to-email-user-when-a-particular-file-is-changed?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create [post-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) to "hook" on commits. In the hook script, you can use the [SVNLOOK](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnlook.html) utility to examine the changeset.You can also evaluate [SVN Notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/)

Comment: Actually email when someone deletes a file ..NOT change !